# Mono and appdomain security/permissionsets

Tags: c#, .net, mono, appdomain

I'm trying to understand AppDomains - and security policies, however I'm having an issue.

Mono doesn't seem to be obeying permissions for me, I am trying to sandbox an AppDomain.

Using .NET it runs just as expected - I get a security permission error because I have absolutely no permissions set.

Under Mono it does not do this. I tried both Mono-2.6 and Mono-2.10.8, mono just runs the program without any errors.

C# code I use for both .NET and mono:

```
namespace AppDomainTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static AppDomain _domain;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomainSetup info = new AppDomainSetup
            {
                ApplicationName = "AppDomainTest",
                ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
            };


            PermissionSet permSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
            //permSet.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
            // permSet.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));


            _domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestDomain", null, info, permSet);

            TestObj o = (TestObj)_domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(TestObj).Assembly.FullName, "AppDomainTest.TestObj");

            Console.WriteLine(o.GetDomainName());

        }
    }


    public class TestObj : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public string GetDomainName()
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
        }
    }
}
```

is there something inherently wrong with what I'm doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono does not implement Code Access Security fully,

http://www.mono-project.com/Todo

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Apr-04.html

So you should not expect it works like .NET in this aspect.